# OSX Yosemite Ruby and Compass Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, yeoman

I setup Ruby through Homebrew and had Compass and Sass installed on my machine which was running 10.9 (Mavericks). Since I've done the update to 10.10 (Yosemite), when I run `grunt serve` on my Yeoman project, I get this error:

```
You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.
```

Any idea what could have borked this? It worked perfectly before.

**UPDATE:**

`which ruby` returns this:

```
/Users/realph/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

`$PATH` returns this:

```
-bash: /Users/realph/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory
```

I've never really understood the whole `$PATH` thing, I just remember reading somewhere that it's good to change it from where OSX points it by default. And I decided to go the Homebrew route.

If anyone could help also explain this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The 10.10 update borked all kinds of things of mine that were installed by Homebrew...  Have you tried reinstalling them?

Comment: @realph in terminal, do which ruby. You also update your question with what's in your path.

Comment: `gem env` will tell you all sorts of information about the Ruby and Rubygems environment. Run that, and append the output to your question by editing it, and pasting the output. Be sure to format it so it's readable.

Comment: Also, instead of using Homebrew, use either [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to install and manage Ruby. They make it very easy to have multiple versions of Ruby installed, and allow switching between different versions. Don't try to run both rbenv and RVM at the same time.

Comment: @Sylar `which ruby` returns this `/Users/realph/.rbenv/shims/ruby`.

Comment: @Sylar Updated original post.

Comment: @realph Ok we are almost there. In terminal, run: `cd`. Then: `nano .bash_profile`. What is inside there?

Comment: @Sylar Theres nothing in there. It's blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in my bash_profile. I get to it by opening up terminal, then:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this to the very top:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

To save and exit:

```
ctrl + x
```

then

```
press y to save and hit enter to exit
```

Close your terminal and reopen then try running your rails commands

If for some reason you do not have a bash profile, create one: http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac

Comment: So when I did `nano ~/.bash_profile` I got this: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`. This was for adding rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal. I added those three lines in your answer to the top of the file and removed the line that was there, but I still get the same error. I also tried it with the `if which` line, but still it throws up the same error.

Comment: @realph I gave you three lines. Try with those three lines in your bash profile only, save, exit and restart your mac. That should work to be honest. Also try to run `gem update --system` after the restart.

Nano is the text editor so you are editing a file, adding those lines.

Comment: Still the same error. I have just those three lines in my bash profile, I've restarted the Mac and Terminal and still the same issue. Not sure what's going on at this point

Comment: Ended up reinstalling compass with `gem install compass` and it seems to work now. Can you help explain what those three lines were for and I'll happily mark this answer?

Comment: It sets the correct path for your gems. Your gems maybe looking for the correct path but your system may generate another path. Setting those keeps it "static". Hard to explain as Im still in my learning days. I MAYBE wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I follow instructions like this, but it always amuses me...I had followed an earlier tutorial that had slightly different instructions...from gorails...but it didn't quite work
then I tried your path method, still no go
finally the gem install compass fixed my sitch. (i'm only using compass and not anything else, so there was prob an easier way)

I'm on Yosemite